# Outlook 2010 Reply as "info@me.com" instead of "me@company.com"

Tags: email, outlook

I receive emails from users who email at an "info@me.com" email that we use on a website we host.

I want to be able to reply as the info address and not my company email.

Does anyone know the process of setting up a mailbox for the info account so that I can click reply and it will say From: info@me.com

I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, 
you have more than one possibility.
First you must activate the fiel "From".

You open a new email in Outlook go under option there is one panel wich calls BCC display (or something like this) and at the right there is one field it calls "advice off" (i don't know the english meaning of this)

[image: Outlook turn "From" on]

If you use a LDAP system you can give your me@company.com the permission for info@me.com

Or the second possibility is that you load a second profile in your Outlook system. Than you could also say send by this profile.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-or-remove-an-e-mail-account-HA001231634.aspx

I hope that could answer your question..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange, set the MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property (you must have the right to send on behalf of that mailbox).

If you are sending through SMTP, see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#14